# Creation of recursive value in Scala

Tags: scala

I was given the following Scala code representing a recursive value:

```
class Cons(elem: Int, next: => Cons)
val x = new Cons(1, x)
```

I get the example but I'm trying to understand the details. In particular, what does the notation  `=> Cons` do? Is it give me no arguments (Unit) and I'll give you a Cons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost, it's a `by-name` parameter:

> By-name parameters are evaluated every time they are used. They won’t be evaluated at all if they are unused. This is similar to replacing the by-name parameters with the passed expressions. They are in contrast to by-value parameters. To make a parameter called by-name, simply prepend => to its type.

It behaves like a function (it actually is under the hood) but you don't need the function application `()` to read it. Every time you use the parameter, the block that evaluates to it is reevaluated.

You can read about it [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/by-name-parameters.html).

Answer (score 3):

`x` is uninitalised until `new Cons(1, x)` evaluates, which means it has value `null` until then, however `x` is itself an argument to `Cons` constructor. If parameter is declared by-value, then it is evaluated **before** it passed in. In this case `new Cons(1, x)` becomes `new Cons(1, null)` which is not what we want. Instead we can declare the parameter as **by-name** using `=>` notation to delay the evaluation of the argument. Now `new Cons(1, x)` becomes something like

```
new Cons(1, () => x))
```

This give `val x` opportunity to become properly initalised before it is used.

By-name:

```
class Cons(elem: Int, next: => Cons) {
  def n = next
}
val x: Cons = new Cons(1, x)

x.n
// res0: Cons = Cons@f523e05
```

By-value

```
class Cons(elem: Int, next: Cons) {
  def n = next
}
val x: Cons = new Cons(1, x)

x.n
// res0: Cons = null
```